# Trouble writing a file with CronJob in Heroku using writeFileSync()

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku, cron

I am trying to repeatedly update a file using a cronjob. Eventually, this is going to be more complicated but for now I'm trying to figure out my current problem. I know the code below is somewhat over-complicated because I preserved the basic structure while trying to problem solve. Here is the server file:

```
// server.js

var express  = require('express');
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var http = require('http');
var fs      = require("fs");
var curtainup = require('./diagnoseleak.js');
var url     = require("url" );

var app = express();

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
//run the CronJob
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('0 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log("running");
  var date = new Date();
  console.log("Ran at: "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes());
  curtainup.doitnow();
} , null, true, 'America/New_York');
```

And here is the file referenced called `diagnoseleak.js`:

```
var fs      = require("fs");
var mostRecentLocation  = "./config/pullfiles/mostRecent55.txt";

module.exports = {
  doitnow: function(){
    var writethefile = function(){
      fs.writeFileSync(mostRecentLocation, "A file called mostRecent55 should be create with this text", { flag: 'w' });
      console.log("This should write to the console");
    }
    writethefile();
  }
}
```

From the directory that houses the server file, I type the following into cmd:

```
git add .
git commit -m "adding files"
git push heroku master
heroku run bash
```

Then into the bash window I type:

```
cd config/pullfiles
ls -l
```

AND...no file called `mostRecent55.txt` appears. Am I looking in the wrong place? Eventually I want to be able to update a file, but I have a feeling I'm either looking in the wrong place for this `mostRecet55.txt` file or going about the process of writing it incorrectly.

Comment: What's the folder structure and also do you see the console log?

Comment: Yea I see the console log. The server.js file is on my computer in a folder called node which also contains the procfile and the sub folders  config/pullfiles

Answer (score 2):

`heroku` doesn't let you write files onto the filesystem where your app is stored. You would need to use an add-on, database or external service of some kind. The only exception seems to be `/tmp` which is only temporary storage